# Why can't I use a getter in a copy constructor?

Tags: c++

I have worked out a complex class as follow:

```
class Complex{
    public:
        Complex(const Complex &);
        double getRreal(){
            return real;
        }
    private:
        double real, img;
};

Complex::Complex(const Complex &Z){
    real = Z.getReal();
}
```

However, the compiler gives me an error:

> passing ‘const Complex’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘double Complex::getReal()’ discards qualifiers

What does this error mean?

By the way, I know that I can simply use

```
real = Z.real;
```

to copy the real part to "this" from Z, but I think it is wired because I can access and modify a private data in the input object "Z". Although the object Z is also an instance of class "Complex", here we doesn't actually aiming on "doing something" for Z. Z is simply an argument for the function doing something for the object "this". Is it safe?

I am not a native speaker. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: update  `double getRreal()` to `double getRreal() const`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are passing a `const` reference (as you should) you can only call `const` methods. Make the getter `const`. There is no reason for it not be `const` anyway.

```
double getRreal() const {
    return real;
}
```

But you don't even need to do that, you can just use the data member directly, and do the initialization in the constructor initialization list:

```
Complex::Complex(const Complex &Z) : real(Z.real)
{
}
```

Or, if you care about the imaginary part `img` (which I presume you do), just let the compiler generated copy constructor do its thing, and remove your own. That would be the best solution.

Comment: @柏均葉 It is a rule of the language. To enforce `const` correctness. Otherwise, you would be able to mutate something that is supposed to be `const`.